# Writing a continous 'for' loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm new to java and was studying on `for` loops from the online tutorials and a question stuck my mind. I will explain my doubt using an example.

Lets say there is an `int` `array` of size `4` with elements `{1, 2, 3, 4}`.
Suppose a user wants to print the elements of the `array` in a way like :

```
{3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4}
```

The user wants to print the array from the third number till the end of the array and if the array ends, the array should start again from the first and this goes on until the total numbers printed should be `10`. 
Can this be possible ? or is there any way we can achieve this ?

Can the loop be printed again from the first after it ends? I tried thinking of using `List` but I was not able to come up with any answer. Kindly help me giving your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: yes it's possible and don't need a list

Comment: Look into the modulus operator, and you should stop when you print 10 elements.

Comment: Can you suggest me the way to proceed this with modulus operator. hint would do. i'll think of it

Answer (score 3):

You would use the modulo `%` operator to loop through the array multiple times. The code below also prints the numbers in the format you described.

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int start = 2; // 0 indexed position of 3rd number
int numTimesToPrint = 10;

System.out.print("{");
for (int i = 0; i < numTimesToPrint; i++) {
    if (i > 0) System.out.print(",");
    System.out.print(array[(i + start) % array.length]);
}
System.out.print("}");
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's certainly possible. Something like

```
public int[] buildArray(final int[] source, final int start, final int length) {
    int index = start;
    final int[] result = new int[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result[i] = source[index++];
        if (index == source.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

To Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int[] source = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    final int[] result = buildArray(source, 2, 10);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

Prints

```
[3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Using `buildArray(source, 2, 15);` results in

```
[3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Note that this solution does not account for parameter validating.
For example, if:

- `source == null`, or
- `source.length == 0`, or
- `start < 0`, or
- `start >= source.length`

then an Exception will be thrown.

Comment: Seems like overkill for the question, but is 100% effective. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    System.out.print("{");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[(2 + i) % 4]);
        if (9 != i)
            System.out.print(",");
        else
            System.out.println("}");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following code:-

```
 public static void print () 
 {
     int[] array = {1,2,3,4};
     int count = 0;
     boolean if_later = false;
     boolean done = false;

     while (true) {
         if (if_later) {
             for (int i = 3; i < array.length; ++i) {
                  System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
                  ++count;
                  if (count == 10) {
                      done = true;
                      break;
                  }   
             } 
         } else {
             for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                 System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
                 ++count;
                 if (count == 10) {
                     done = true;
                     break;
                 }   
             } 
         }

         /*
          * If all numbers are printed then break
          */
         if (done) {
             break;
         }

         /*
          * Toggle the boolean flag for printing
          * from the front of the array and the 
          * back of the array.
          */
         if (if_later) {
             if_later = false;
         } else {
             if_later = true;
         }
     }
  }
```